# In the sacct command in the Slurm workload manager, is there a way to find the maximum of the "Elapsed" column or sort it?

Tags: slurm

Currently, I am running a job array of 1000 using Slurm. When it is done, I use `sacct` to see how much time was actually taken. I would like to see what was the longest running job. It would be the largest value under the `"Elapsed"` column. Is there a way to sort it?

```
sacct -o reqmem,maxrss,averss,elapsed  -j 44523498
    ReqMem     MaxRSS     AveRSS    Elapsed
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     800Mn                         02:24:15
     800Mn    655756K    655756K   02:24:15
     800Mn       844K       344K   02:24:17
     800Mn                         02:10:08
     800Mn    631912K    631912K   02:10:08
     800Mn      1032K       344K   02:10:08
     800Mn                         01:38:14
     800Mn    635304K    635304K   01:38:14
     800Mn       848K       348K   01:38:14
     800Mn                         02:28:04
```

This is what I have below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to display the `elapsed` as the first column and use the `sort` command. `sort` sorts alphanumerically, which will work with the Slurm time formatting thanks to the 2-digit padding.

```
sacct -o elapsed,reqmem,maxrss,averss  -j 44523498 | sort
```

You can additionally use the `-n` flag to avoid the header lines, if you do not want them to clutter the output.

Note that `sort` can be told to sort on a specific column, with the `-k` flag but here the number of column is different for job steps and job summary. You can remove the job step information (which is redundant w.r.t elapsed) with `-X`.

Comment: switch to `sort -r` (reverse) if you want the longest jobs on top